# GreaseMonkey setTimeout doesn't work even with references (FF4)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have this in my UserScript file:

```
window.testMyFunctionBLah = function() {
    alert('hey');
}

window.setTimeout( testMyFunctionBLah, 1000 );

alert('hi');
```

I see `hi`, but not `hey`, and I can't figure it out. I'm using Firefox 4 and do NOT have NoScript installed. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in FF 4.0.

See ["alert + setTimeout = failure"](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1318#issuecomment-975522).